# Auth Component not checking password automatically in cakephp 2.4

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I downloaded the recent version of cakephp that is cakephp 2.4.

When I am using Auth component it is not checking password.

When I see sql dump it shows

```sql
SELECT User.id, User.role_id, User.username, User.password,
User.email, User.first_name, User.last_name, User.activation_key,
User.status, User.created, User.modified
FROM cakephp.users AS User WHERE User.username = 'admin'
AND User.status = 1 LIMIT 1
```

It should be

```sql
SELECT User.id, User.role_id, User.username, User.password, User.email,
User.first_name, User.last_name, User.activation_key, User.status,
User.created, User.modified FROM cakephp.users AS User
WHERE User.username = 'admin'
AND User.password = '32ddqdsd34sfgtbvge434' AND User.status = 1 LIMIT 1
```

My Auth component code is

```
$this->Auth->userModel = 'User';

$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
                            'Form' => array(
                            'scope' => array('User.status' => 1)
                            )
                        );

$this->Auth->loginError     =   __("login_failed_invalid_username_or_password");

$this->Auth->loginAction    =   array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login');  

$this->Auth->loginRedirect  =    array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'dashboard');

$this->Auth->authError      =   __('you_must_login_to_view_this_information');

$this->Auth->autoRedirect   =   true;
```

Comment: Cakephp will check the password after retrieving the record. Try typing and incorrect password. Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

The hashing algorithm has changed in 2.4. The password check is now done with PHP and a different has type is used.

In your model

```
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {

    $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);

}

return true;

}
```

and your controller

```
 public $components = array(
    'Session',
    /* add Auth component and set  the urls that will be loaded after the login and logout actions is performed */
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'dashboard'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'home')
    )
);
```

make time to read this

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

Answer (score 0):

It won't do password check in one sql with finding user.
Cake from 2.4 will find user (you see this query) and then check password.
You need to have correct passwod in table to get true from Auth->login

Solution: [Login using AuthComponent in CakePHP 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844884/login-using-authcomponent-in-cakephp-2-4)