# Login using AuthComponent in CakePHP 2.4

Tags: php, cakephp

I think CakePHP didn't discussed about 2.4 AuthComponent elaborately. As 2.4 has new algorithm  for hashing (bcrypt), CookBook should make it clear or I didn't got the point. I found many people has this problem. AuthComponent do not check for passwords if I see SQL dumps. Here my code:

```
//UsersController
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'home'),
    'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout')
    )
);
public function login(){
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array());
        }
    }
}

//UserModel
class UserModel extends AppModel{
}
//Login.ctp
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->end('Login');
```

Sql dump:

```
SELECT User.id, User.username, User.password, User.pass_hint, User.joined FROM 
oes.users AS User WHERE User.username = 'guest' LIMIT 1
```

I found that `$this->Auth->login()` never returning `true` whether my login credentials correct or not. But I want a successful login, using AuthComponent.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What data do you have in your table? You should see a hashed password in your `User.password`. If you do not know how to get the hashed password, do this: `debug($this->Auth->password('test123'))` in anywhere you can access from browser, and so `test123` will be the password, and the 40 char hashed string should be in your table.

Comment: I didn't hash my password in database table. Don't it work without hashed passwords? Don't even md5 passwords?

Comment: Ok, I did what you suggested. But this time it's back to login form after hitting login button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AuthComponent do not check for passwords if I see SQL dumps
```

Wrong: `AuthComponent` does check for passwords. It's pulling `User.password` and there is where they check for password.

`AuthComponent` uses `BasicAuthenticate` to check password. It runs [`getUser`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-BasicAuthenticate.html#71-85) to fetch the user, and uses `BaseAuthenticate` to check password from [`BaseAuthenticate::_findUser()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-BaseAuthenticate.html#93). It's not hard to follow, and that's where magic happens.

The rule here is, you will need to pre-hash your password in your database and so it will work out of the box.

To get the hash token, use

```
echo $this->Auth->password('the-chosen-password'); //DEPRECATED since 2.4.0
```

or use [`Security`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Security.html#_hash) utility:

```
echo Security::hash('the-chosen-password', null, true);
```

Comment: So, how can I hash a password(before saving to table) on the fly when a new user account is created?

Comment: Typically, what I did is in the beforeSave of User model, I do a hash over the password before saving, if it's a create. Your business logic could be different, and my method is not the only way. For a suggestion only.

Comment: Would you please consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865296/encrypting-password-when-adding-new-user)?