# Hashing password when adding new user

Tags: cakephp, encryption, cakephp-2.4

CakePHP 2.4

While adding a new user I must hash passwords before storing it in the Database. To do so I did:

```
//UsersController
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'home', 'home'),
    'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout')
    )
);
public function add(){
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->User->create();
        if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Saved!');
        }
    }
}

//UserModel
public function beforeSave(){
    if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password']))
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = md5($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    return true;
}

//add.ctp
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('text', array('label'=>'Username', 'name'=>'username'));
echo $this->Form->input('text', array('label'=>'Full name', 'name'=>'fullname'));
echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label'=>'Password', 'name'=>'password'));
echo $this->Form->input('text', array('label'=>'Password hint', 'name'=>'pass_hint'));
echo $this->Form->input('text', array('label'=>'Email', 'name'=>'email'));
echo $this->Form->input('text', array('label'=>'Contact', 'name'=>'cell'));
echo $this->Form->end('Create account');
```

But the thing is passwords are being stored without being hashed!

Thanks in advance...

**Update:** Changed view code to

```
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label'=>'Username'));
echo $this->Form->input('fullname', array('label'=>'Full name'));
echo $this->Form->input('pwd', array('label'=>'Password', 'type'=>'password'));
echo $this->Form->input('pass_hint', array('label'=>'Password hint'));
echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label'=>'Email'));
echo $this->Form->input('cell', array('label'=>'Contact'));
echo $this->Form->end('Create account');
```

Comment: You are not encrypting it, you are hashing it. That's a difference :) Tip: See http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/

Comment: Good article. But this time table gets nothing in the password filed. beforeSave() is `if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['pwd'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['pwd']);
        }`

Comment: And why using md5? You should at least use sha1 - maybe better even one of the new standards like blowfish. You need to name your field pwd as well, if you want to do it that way (you can't/shouldn't still name it password then). If you can't get it to work, use my behavior for a clean and more secure approach.

Comment: Yes I renamed my view as well. I tried with your way but still no luck. I think my beforeSave() isn't being executed. Is that possible? I checked pr($this->data) and debug($this->data) but nothing is printed, my debug level is 2.

Comment: Depends on how your controller code looks like for this action :) I cannot read your mind.

Comment: I have provided controllers `add()` function with my question. Please have a look.

Comment: Where is your `$this->User->create()` when creating/adding a new user? Also, `$this->Form->input('text', ..` multiple times, that is NOT how it works. Your form is totally invalid. I highly recommend that you bake your code first to see how things are actually done.

Comment: see the update whether it's ok or not?

Comment: `$this->User->create()` is still missing in your action - again: bake your code than you see how its done. It might work in your case, but can easily break, once you do sth in your beforeFilter() callbacks etc.

Comment: your suggestion worked! thanks :)

Comment: one thing I want to mention is `AuthComponent::password()` is deprecated, you should use `Security::hash()` in cake 2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why but I just baked a project with user table and found that CakePHP 2.4 is naming the model as `User` rather than `UserModel`. So, I renamed mine from `UserModel` to `User` and magically is worked for me :)

Comment: Ah yea, just as if you haven't notice, they follow something like what Java did - class names should be identical to the file name, for example, in `User.php`, you do `class User extends AppModel` etc.

Answer (score 0):

you are changing the default behavior by setting the name attributes in your input type,

Remove the name attributes then it'll work,

In your user model beforesave function you are checking for

`if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password']))`

which is no longer exist since you are setting password like this

`echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label'=>'Password', 'name'=>'password'));`

change it to

`echo $this->Form->input('User.password', array('label'=>'Password'));`

**Update**

and also Update the form like this then it'll work perfectly.

```
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label'=>'Username'));
echo $this->Form->input('fullname', array('label'=>'Full name'));
echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label'=>'Password', 'name'=>'password'));
echo $this->Form->input('pass_hint', array('label'=>'Password hint'));
echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label'=>'Email'));
echo $this->Form->input('cell', array('label'=>'Contact'));
echo $this->Form->end('Create account');
```

Comment: What if I want custom label?

Comment: custom label you are setting using `array('label' => 'name')`

Comment: oops this isn't still working for me. I tried with and without `'name'=>'password'` but no luck. here is the view html source code that is being rendered `<div class="input password"><label for="UserPassword">Password</label><input name="data[User][password]" type="password" id="UserPassword"/></div>`

Comment: just check what data you are getting in `beforeSave` callback by doing `pr($this->data)`.

Comment: set your debug to 2 and then try, `pr` will only work when debug mode is 2 or try `print_r($this->data)`

Comment: SQL dump: `INSERT INTO `oes`.`users` (`username`, `fullname`, `password`, `pass_hint`, `email`, `cell`) VALUES ('guest', 'testing', '1111', '1234', 'email@yahoo.com', '01234567890')`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37577/discussion-between-anil-kumar-and-coolbrain)

Comment: `Configure::write('debug', 2);` and still the same

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37594/discussion-between-anil-kumar-and-coolbrain)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a vital part of add actions:

```
public function add(){
    if ($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->User->create(); // important!
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Saved!');
        }
    }
}
```

It might work in your case (sometimes), but can easily break, once you do sth in your beforeFilter() callbacks etc

Comment: I added it later(forgot to update my question) but not worked.